# Passing two or more values to javascript through onchange event

Tags: javascript, ajax, zend-framework2

I have `selectbox` for districts on the base of selection relevant cities are displayed.

```
foreach ($pr_districts as $list) {

    $valueid = $this->escapeHtml ($list->id);  
    $value = $this->escapeHtml ($list->d_name); 
    $districts_option [] = array( 'value' => $valueid, 'label' => $value );
}    
    $district_form->get('districts')->setAttributes(array('options' => $districts_option, 'onChange'=>"getCities(this.value)"));
```

Here `id` (stored in `value`) of selected district is passed to `getCities()`.

I want to pass province id `p_id` also to `getCities()` and then access it there. I don't know how to do this.

Please guide me friends. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you could pass it in like:

```
...
$district_form->get('districts')
    ->setAttributes(
        array(
            'options' => $districts_option,
            'onChange'=>"getCities(this.value, '$yourIDHere')"
        )
     );
```

Comment: Notice that the `setAttributes()` with the key: 'options', will call `setValueOptions()`, which will update the `InArray` validator. This will be deprecated some time, see: [Zend\Form\Element\Select::setAttributes()](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/Element/Select.php#L162). So it might be better to call `->setValueOptions()` separately.